# Switch grub2 between ubuntu 14 to 16

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, bootrepair

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 installed in first disk of my laptop. Also I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed in second disk of my laptop.

After a brutal shutting down(battery issue), `grub2` doesn't work any more. I have to use `boot-repair` from a live CD to fix it but then it set up using the grub2 on Ubuntu 14(Before it used the grub2 from Ubuntu 16 to boot).

I remember when I launched `boot-repair` it asked me the question: `Is the disk (name of the disk that I had Ubuntu 14.04) a removable device?` I answered `No` and thought that's the reason.

Although I tried `boot-repair` again and answered `Yes`, it keeps setting up using the grub2 of Ubuntu 14.04. Anyone know how to configure to switch it back to use the grub2 on Ubuntu 16.04 because I want to remove Ubuntu 14.04 later? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Grub is not bound to a version of Linux - thus if you can modify the config to boot Ubuntu 16.04 you can safely delete 14.04.  Alternatively have you looked at using super grub to boot into your 16.04 instance and then reinstalling grub?

Comment: I tried to use grub-customiser on ubuntu 16 but then it doesn't save the setting at all and screw up the boot system, that's how I realise it used the grub2 of ubuntu 14, when I tried grub-customiser on ubuntu 14 and it saved the setting. Reinstall grub2 on ubuntu 16 seems too risky for me cause I almost used boot-repair all the time to fix issue so I don't know much how to do with manuall install.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to temporarily unplug the disk with ubuntu 14.04, restore the grub in Ubuntu 16.04, connect the disk with ubuntu 14.04, select the boot from the disk ubuntu 16.04 in BIOS, go to 16.04 instance and update the grub configuration. And always boot from disk 16.04. To make the menu grub with different names 16.04 and 14.04, install grub-customizer (http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-16-04-lts/)

Comment: temporarily unplug the disk with ubuntu 14.04!!!! Repair grub without 14.04